# Why is the throughput of bandwidth simulation with cps = 0 almost the same with cps = 12800000 in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, bandwidth, throughput

I have tested bandwidth simulation in jmeter (version 3.1) with Non GUI execution but got an unexpected result that is the throughput of cps = 0 is almost the same with cps = 12800000.

I just added these 2 parameters in jmeter.properties and user.properties:

httpclient.socket.http.cps=12800000

httpclient.socket.https.cps=12800000

Here is my test plan and the result:

- Thread Group

  - Users = 100
  - Ramp Up = 1
  - Loop Count = 100
- HTTP Request

  - Server Name or IP = jmeter.apache.org
- Result

  - CPS = 0
    [image]
    [image]
  - CPS = 12800000
    [image]
    [image]

And weird thing is the throughput of cps = 12800000 is greater than throughput of cps = 0. It should be cps = 0 > cps = 12800000

Please advise.

Thanks,

Rio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [How to simulate network bandwidth in JMeter?](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/Controlling%20Bandwidth%20in%20JMeter%20to%20simulate%20different%20networks) article:

> Fast Ethernet : 100 Mbit/s **12800000**

So you are trying to limit the bandwidth to 100 Mbit/s which is approximately 12.5 megabytes per second.

In both cases you receive ~400 **kilobytes** in 4 seconds which means **100 kilobytes per second** which means that there is 12.4 megabytes/second headroom therefore your throttling setting doesn't have any impact. You need to set desired simulated bandwidth to be lower than 100 cps in order to see the throttling effect.

In regards to the "Throughput" - according to [JMeter Glossary](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)

> **Throughput** is calculated as requests/unit of time. The time is calculated from the start of the first sample to the end of the last sample. This includes any intervals between samples, as it is supposed to represent the load on the server.
>
> The formula is: `Throughput = (number of requests) / (total time).`

So please don't be confused as `requests per second` and `bytes per second` are different beasts, the latter one can be monitored [Bytes Throughput Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/BytesThroughput/) listener, but remember, you will need to reach the throughput of more than 12.5 megabytes per second in order to see the impact of your throttling.

See [How to Simulate Different Network Speeds in Your JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-simulate-different-network-speeds-your-jmeter-load-test) article for comprehensive information and example scenarios.

---

P.S. Don't load test public websites without explicit permission of the sites owners, you may be at least banned for an attempt of DOS attack

Comment: Hi Dimitri,

Thank you for your explaination.

I have been wondering why my Local Area Connection Status says Speed: 100.0 Mbps (12500 KBps) but I get only 100 KBps. Is it because my internet provider limited my internet speed?

And after I set the cps under 100, I got 48.5/min for throughput. Does it work?

Thanks,
Rio

Comment: In regards to Internet connection speed contact your Internet provider. For setting cps under 100 - you need to **restart JMeter to pick the properties up**. Another option is passing them via -J command-line arguments like `jmeter -Jhttpclient.socket.http.cps=100`, in this case restart won't be required. See [Configuring Jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) and [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for details.

Comment: Hi Dimitri, I would like to confirm about your statement: In both cases you receive ~400 kilobytes in 4 seconds which means 100 kilobytes per second. If I see the screenshot again, it is 4 minutes not 4 seconds, it means ~400 kilobytes in 4 minutes = 400 kilobytes / 240 seconds = 1 kilobytes = 8 kilobits, so cps will be 8 kilobits * 1024 / 8 = 1024. Please advise.